# How to Compose Geometric Mean in cvxpy

Tags: cvxpy

I want to write

```
x + z <= sqrt(y(x - z**2/y))
```

using `geo_mean` and `quad_over_lin` from `cvxpy`, but I see that `geo_mean` takes in a vector.

I'm trying something like

```
[x + z <= cp.geo_mean(np.array([y, x - cp.quad_over_lin(z, y)]))]
```

doesn't work. How do I build up the geometric mean using cvxpy atoms?

Comment: ``yx>=(x+z)^2+z^2`` is a convex reformulation of your constraint assuming ``x,y>=0``, which you can enter as a Lorenz cone (rotated quadratic cone) or using ``y>=quad_over_lin([x+z,z],x)``